# AWS Lambda: List Executions/Describe Executions via Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWSStepFunctions has a method `listExecutions` and `describeExecution` in the Java SDK.

However I don't see similar methods on the `AWSLambda` object nor any alternate suggestion in the documentation.

Anybody know how to do this?

Resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Operations.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html

Comment: Ultimately there isn't something like this though I like the idea.  You can [get log events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#getLogEvents-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.GetLogEventsRequest-) once you have the log group name and log stream name.  And you can get those too.  But you may have thousands of events and you need to look for something like `START RequestId: d28d47fd-9a2e-4a6c-b2df-ff0cc97bd808 Version: $LATEST` in the logs.

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for the response. Strange that this exists on StepFunctions but not on Lambda itself.